# Google maps cluster

Tags: google-maps, cluster-computing

(sorry for my english)
I want make cluster, but i have error 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getPosition' 
Coords i take from database

```
       function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.323678, 44.0);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 7,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        setMarkers(map, markers);
  }  

var markers = [ <? for ($i=0; $i<count($cords); $i++) 
{if((float)$cords["$i"]["location_lat"]<>0 AND (float)$cords["$i"]["location_lng"]<>0  ){echo "[".(float)$cords["$i"]["location_lat"].",
".(float)$cords["$i"]["location_lng"]." ,
 '".$cords["$i"]["image"]."', 
'".$cords["$i"]["name"]."']";
if ($i+1<count($cords))echo ",\n\r";}}?> ];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 });
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, locations);
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);

            latlngbounds.extend(myLatLng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,   
                title: locations[i][3]
            });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent("<img src='image/"+ locations[i][2] +"' height='150' width='300'> <br> <b>"+ locations[i][3] +"</b> " );
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        }
      })(marker, i));
           }
   map.setCenter( latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(latlngbounds));    
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't stated the index of the array that you want to do "getPosition",
your code is so messy..
:)